# What is the meaning behind "WARNING:tensorflow:Passing a `GraphDef` to the SummaryWriter is deprecated"?

Tags: tensorflow

What is the meaning behind that warning? I'd love it if someone could explain what a Graph object is and why passing sess.graph_def shouldn't be done.

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logistic_logs/',graph_def=sess.graph_def)
```

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow you used to define your operations as an acyclic computational graph. With introduciton of Tensorflow 2.0 we no longer have a session object and together with session, the predefined full graph containing all operations is also gone. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2) under Eager Execution.

You can learn more about tensorflow graphs and how to visualize them [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/graphs).